# SwiftUI DragGesture inconsistencies with location and start location

Tags: macos, swiftui, draggesture

I'm building a SwiftUI macOS app.

I've got a basic Rectangle shape with a drag gesture on it.

In the `onEnded` handler, I am wanting to determine if the user has effectively tapped on the object. I do this by checking that the width and height of the translation are both zero.

(There are reasons I'm not using a tap gesture).

```
Rectangle()
    .size(.init(width:50, height: 50))
    .fill(Color.blue.opacity(0.01))
    .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance:0)
                .onChanged { gesture in
                    // Ommited
                }
                .onEnded { gesture in
                    print("startLocation", gesture.startLocation)
                    print("start", gesture.location)
                    print("translation", gesture.translation)
                    
                    if gesture.translation == .zero {
                        print("tap")
                    }

                    print()
                }
    )
```

I'm getting issues where translations are being reported with unexpected values.

The values reported differ based on where I click in the rectangle.

Here's a set of groups of individual clicks. The `translation` is derived from the `startLocation` and `location` fields.

You can see variation between the `startLocation` and the `location` fields. If it was a very small variation I could debounce, however the fact that sometimes I get a value of `3` makes me wonder why such a variation could happen (I'm being over the top careful to execute the click without movement).

Does anyone know why this variation is creeping in?

```
startLocation (263.5149841308594, 144.3092803955078)
start (263.51495361328125, 144.30926513671875)
translation (-3.0517578125e-05, -1.52587890625e-05)

startLocation (276.2882995605469, 144.43479919433594)
start (276.288330078125, 144.434814453125)
translation (3.0517578125e-05, 1.52587890625e-05)

startLocation (274.3827209472656, 162.3402557373047)
start (274.38275146484375, 162.34027099609375)
translation (3.0517578125e-05, 1.52587890625e-05)

startLocation (264.81805419921875, 167.47662353515625)
start (264.81805419921875, 167.47662353515625)
translation (0.0, 0.0)
tap

startLocation (254.5931396484375, 135.4690399169922)
start (254.5931396484375, 135.46905517578125)
translation (0.0, 1.52587890625e-05)

startLocation (259.1647033691406, 140.26919555664062)
start (259.16473388671875, 140.26919555664062)
translation (3.0517578125e-05, 0.0)
```

### Edit

As pointed out below, the value of `3` is actually `3e-05 = 0.00003` which I missed at the time of writing. However, still looking for information as to why the tap gesture will have zero translation on repeated clicks in some points of the Rectangle, but have a non zero translation in others.

Comment: As I mentioned in the Developer forum, you are not getting 3, it's 3e-05 = 0.00003 a very very small number.

Comment: Oh jeez.... how did I miss this. Thanks for pointing that out. Any ideas why it changes dependent on where I click in the Rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
if gesture.translation.width/UIScreen.main.bounds.width < 0.05 &&
gesture.translation.height/UIScreen.main.bounds.height < 0.05 
{
    print("tap") // 0.01 ~ 0.05
}
```

This way works, regardless of the size of the device and width & height, it is always constant as it falls in percentages.